# Mocking Webclient call. It throws NPE in .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(data)) line

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, webclient

Trying to Mock WebClient call. Unable to mock the .body method. Even after mocking it. It throws NullPointerException.

```
            Mono<String> response = webClient.post()
                    .uri(workflowApp.get(CommonConstants.TOKEN_URL))
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
                        httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(encodedClientData);
                    })
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(data))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                    .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
                        String accessTokenValue = tokenResponse.get(TokenConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)
                                .textValue();
                        log.info("accessTokenValue {}", accessTokenValue);

                        return webclientnoproxy.post()
                                .uri(workflowApp.get(CommonConstants.ENDPOINT_URL))
                                .headers(h -> {
                                    h.clear();
                                    h.setBearerAuth(accessTokenValue);
                                    h.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                                })

                                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(moRequestWorkflow),
                                        MORequestWorkflow.class))
                                .retrieve()
                                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> {
                                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                            .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new Exception(errorBody)));
                                })
                                .bodyToMono(String.class);

                    });
```

I tried the below code in Junit. I have been trying to mock the .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(data)) line but still getting Null Pointer exception on the line. Could not mock the .body method.

```
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
        when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
        when(requestHeadersMock.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
        when(requestBodySpecMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
        when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class))
                .thenReturn(monoJson);
```

If anyone faced this scenario, help me to resolve this.

Comment: did you try mockito-inline for mocking bahevior for static methods?

Comment: No i have not. Can you provide any reference.

Comment: I think NullPointer throws BodyInserters by using static method, So here is info on how to mock it https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: where is your stack trace of the null pointer exception? it needs to be in the question

Comment: also, you have "It throws NPE in .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(data))" in the subject but you have ".body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher" in the code in question... please fix the question to show the actual problem